# Sort an array of dates using usort() and sort() functions

Tags: php, date, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort an array of dates using usort() and sort() functions by the timestamp converted by mktime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438441/sort-an-array-of-dates-using-usort-and-sort-functions-by-the-timestamp-conve)

I'm trying to sort an array of dates using sort() and usort() only - without using mktime(). I'm trying to compare month, day and year, but can not get the correct result, plus it gives me a bunch of warnings.
Will appreciate any help.

```
$dates = array ('10-10-2003', '2-17-2002', '2-16-2003','1-01-2005', '10-10-2004' );
function toTime($date) {

return sort ($date, SORT_STRING);
}

function sortByTime($a, $b) {
$a = toTime($a);
$b = toTime($b);
if($a == $b) {
    return 0;
}
return $a < $b ? -1 : 1 ;
}

usort($dates, 'sortByTime');
print_r($dates);
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: What are you doing in your toTime function?

Comment: Aerik, in toTime function I'm trying just to sort the array string. I tried to separate mm, dd, yyyy, but no success.

Comment: vascowite, yes - this was my question too. But here I can not use mktime() converter.

Comment: What warnings do you get? Can you include your toTime function in the question?

Comment: @Emil Vikstrom:
function toTime($date) {
    $list = list($month, $day, $year) = explode('-', $date);
    return sort($list); }  I'm getting warnings for sort() - it asks for array, for explode() function - second parameter should be string. I know this function is incorrect and maybe really stupid. I'm just started to learn PHP, so getting my hands dirty. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: @Emil Vikstrom, I also tried function toTime($date) { return sort ($date, SORT_STRING); }, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

> use [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) to sort by keys with a callback
>
> in the callback simply parse the date to a timestamp and use a simple comparison

Sudo Code :

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    global $array;
    return strcmp($array[$a]['db'], $array[$b]['db']);
}

uksort($array, 'cmp');
```

Comment: can not use uksort() :( only usort() and sort()

Comment: that's the formal education concept :) Break your head but don't use convenient methods :)